# Pass variable to Info Window in FusionTableLayer

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I am building a web application that includes a Google Map layered with data from a Google Fusion Table. I have defined the info window for the markers in the Fusion Table and all is rendering as expected, but I have one issue. I need to pass a session variable from my web application to be included in the links that are defined in the info window, but can't seem to find a way to do this. Below is the javascript I am currently using to render the map:

```
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng( 40.4230,-98.7372)
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

// Weather

weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
  temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
});
weatherLayer.setMap(map);

//Hobby Stores

var storeLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: { select: "col2", from: "3991553" },
  map: map,
  supressInfoWindows: true
});

//Club Sites

var siteLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: { select: "col13", from: "3855088" },
  styles: [{ markerOptions: { iconName: "airports" }}],
  map: map,
  supressInfoWindows: true
});
```

I'd like to be able to pass some type of parameter in the call to google.maps.FusionTableLayer that passes a value to be include in the info window, but can't find a way to do this.

To view the actual page, visit [www.dualrates.com](http://www.dualrates.com/pls/apex/f?p=RC:30). Enter your zipcode and select one of the airport markers to see the info window. You may have to zoom the map out to see an airfield.

Comment: You have supressInfoWindows:true which means you are creating and populating the infoWindow, not Fusion Table. If you have the session variable in your page you should be able to add it when the window is created or opened.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how to customize info window content:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_infowindow_content

You would update the following function to include your specific table's information and add the session variable. Assuming you're using php, it might look something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {

  // Change the content of the InfoWindow
  e.infoWindowHtml = e.row['Store Name'].value + "<br>";

  // If the delivery == yes, add content to the window
  if (e.row['delivery'].value == 'yes') {
    e.infoWindowHtml += "Delivers!";
  }

  e.infoWindowHtml += "<?php echo $_SESSION['yourvariable']; ?>";
});
```